# Queue and smart pointers in c++

Tags: c++, stl, queue, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a simple implementation of a tree in C++ using smart pointers. I have done it with regular pointers and wanted to now move on to smart pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;


struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    shared_ptr<TreeNode> left, right;

    TreeNode(const int& value):
        data(value), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};

template<typename T>
class BST {
    public:
        shared_ptr<TreeNode> root;
        BST(): root(nullptr){}
        shared_ptr<TreeNode> _insert(shared_ptr<TreeNode>& rootptr, const T& value);
        void bfs(shared_ptr<TreeNode>& root);
};
```

and this is my bfs function

```
template<typename T>
void BST<T>::bfs(shared_ptr<TreeNode>& root) {
    if(root == nullptr) return;
    queue<TreeNode> bfsqueue;
    bfsqueue.push(root); 
    while (!bfsqueue.empty())
    {
        shared_ptr<TreeNode> current = bfsqueue.front();
        bfsqueue.pop();
        cout<<current->data<<" ";
        if (current->left != nullptr)
        {
            bfsqueue.push(current->left);
        }
        if (current->right != nullptr)
        {
            bfsqueue.push(current->right);
        }    
    }
}
```

Now when I try to call the function I get the following errors;

```
index.cpp: In member function 'void BST<T>::bfs(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>&)':
index.cpp:240:18: error: no matching function for call to 'std::queue<TreeNode>::push(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>&)'
  240 |     bfsqueue.push(root);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/queue:64,
                 from index.cpp:151:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:265:7: note: candidate: 'void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Sequence = std::deque<TreeNode, std::allocator<TreeNode> >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = TreeNode]'
  265 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:265:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>' to 'const value_type&' {aka 'const TreeNode&'}
  265 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:270:7: note: candidate: 'void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Sequence = std::deque<TreeNode, std::allocator<TreeNode> >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = TreeNode]'
  270 |       push(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:270:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>' to 'std::queue<TreeNode>::value_type&&' {aka 'TreeNode&&'}
  270 |       push(value_type&& __x)
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
index.cpp:248:26: error: no matching function for call to 'std::queue<TreeNode>::push(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>&)'
  248 |             bfsqueue.push(current->left);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/queue:64,
                 from index.cpp:151:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:265:7: note: candidate: 'void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Sequence = std::deque<TreeNode, std::allocator<TreeNode> >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = TreeNode]'
  265 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:265:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>' to 'const value_type&' {aka 'const TreeNode&'}
  265 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:270:7: note: candidate: 'void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Sequence = std::deque<TreeNode, std::allocator<TreeNode> >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = TreeNode]'
  270 |       push(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:270:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>' to 'std::queue<TreeNode>::value_type&&' {aka 'TreeNode&&'}
  270 |       push(value_type&& __x)
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
index.cpp:252:26: error: no matching function for call to 'std::queue<TreeNode>::push(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>&)'
  252 |             bfsqueue.push(current->right);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/queue:64,
                 from index.cpp:151:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:265:7: note: candidate: 'void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Sequence = std::deque<TreeNode, std::allocator<TreeNode> >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = TreeNode]'
  265 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:265:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>' to 'const value_type&' {aka 'const TreeNode&'}
  265 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:270:7: note: candidate: 'void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Sequence = std::deque<TreeNode, std::allocator<TreeNode> >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = TreeNode]'
  270 |       push(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_queue.h:270:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>' to 'std::queue<TreeNode>::value_type&&' {aka 'TreeNode&&'}
  270 |       push(value_type&& __x)
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

From what I'm understanding(may be wrong) it's telling me that the push operation is not successful because there's no known conversion for 'std::shared_ptr' to 'const value_type&' meaning push is expecting a const value while what I'm trying to push is a shared_ptr of type TreeNode.

Am i understanding it right? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `TreeNode` and `shared_ptr<TreeNode>` are different types. `queue<TreeNode> bfsqueue;` holds `TreeNode`s and you try to push a `shared_ptr<TreeNode>`. You'd get similar error with raw pointers

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yeah that's quite a silly mistake on my part. Since with raw pointers everything was TreeNode*, I didnt run into this problem. My knowledge of smart pointers is still quite lacking.

Comment: Just wanna mention that for a binary tree, you probably need pointers to left, right and parent nodes.

Comment: I'm fairly new to binary trees and from what I've learned so far, a node has a data field, pointer to left child and a pointer to right child. There's one way link from a parent to a child but no direct link from a child to a parent. Maybe I'll learn more about them later

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid learning 2 things at once. Hack around with smart pointers for a while in simple programs, then deploy them in trees. And when you get back to trees, here's some good viewing: [Leak Freedom by default.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) If I remember correctly this covers linked lists, but the same lessons apply to trees.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. And yes learning these two at once is proving to be confusing so I'll stick to smart pointers for now and will play around with them for now.